# Blazemeter records only the first step

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

I recently upgraded to Windows 11 and I see that the Blazemeter is not working correctly. Blazemeter records only the first step which is loading the URL. When I save the file and open it in JMeter, I see that there is only one transaction controller with one sampler that has a GET call pointing to the server. All the steps after that have not got recorded. Has anyone else experienced that?

Comment: For future reference, please don't use all-capitals in titles. Using all-capitals is the internet-equivalent of shouting, which is pretty rude when you want help.

Answer (score 0):

If by "Blazemeter" you mean [BlazeMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690351377-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium) it doesn't depend on Windows version, it should record whatever [HTTP requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) are executed in the browser.

If your "steps" do generate HTTP Requests - the extension should capture them. In case the extension doesn't and they're happening (you can cross check it using "Network" tab of your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools)) you can raise an issue via [BlazeMeter Support](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207491229-How-to-Open-a-Support-Ticket)

If your "steps" do not generate HTTP Requests - you won't be able to replay them using JMeter, you will need to go for browser automation framework like [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/)